# how to place banner on the view at run time in iphone sdk 3.0 onwards

Tags: iphone

I want to display banner at the top of the view i know that for that iAd is available but it works on 4.o onwards and i want to display it from sdk 3.0 onwards so can any one give me the links or video which give me the proper steps to create it.

thanx & regards
Priyanka..

Comment: You should accept more answers to your previous questions. Otherwise, you'll find it harder to receive answers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimum requirement to run iAd is iOS4 or higher. Many iOS users are switching to iOS4 so you can go ahead and cater to that. Cheers.